# PayPal Item(s) w/ Description on Review Page

Tags: paypal

Using the PayPal REST api, I'm passing in this to new payments:

```
transactions: [
      {
        amount: {
          total: "10.00",
          currency: "USD",
          details: {
            subtotal: "10.00"
          }
        },
        description: "My item description."
      }
    ],
```

<sub>Snippet of the actual request</sub>

On the PayPal approve page, though, only the subtotal is displayed - nowhere does the description show up, nor do individual item listings - only the subtotal in USD shows up.

How can I make individual items with descriptions in the REST API checkout? I'm using `&useraction=commit` by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to pass over the line items in the SetExpressCheckout API call that you are making.  There is a list of variable that can be passed over in the [developers guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_nvpapi_developerguide.pdf).  I have checked with our engineers, and this feature has not been pushed live yet.  Line items will be supported, but the feature is not yet live with the New REST API's.

Comment: Thanks, please push that asap

Comment: That was March 2013, now August 2013, anyone know if this is live yet?

Comment: Jun 2014 and passing items and description in a payment transaction will only show the cart items.  The description will only be visible if you do not pass items. :(